# Create a 'Counter' column in SQL vertica

Tags: sql, counter, vertica

I want to add a 'counter' column to a set of data so that I get the following:

Input

```
COLUMN_NAME
<value1>
<value2>
...
<valuen>
```

Output

```
COLUMN_NAME || COUNTER_COLUMN
<value1>    || 1
<value2>    || 2
...         || ...
<valuen>    || n
```

I'm assuming my original data is already sorted as I want it to be.

Thanks!

Comment: Which DBMS you are using?

Comment: I am using Vertica SQL. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL:

```
SELECT t.COLUMN_NAME, 
       @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS COUNTER_COLUMN
FROM YourTableName t, 
   (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
```

Comment: I get an error saying "Syntax error at or near ":"  Not sure if the @rownum is supported in vertica?

Comment: Did you notice the vertical tag?

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer:

```
SELECT 
t.COLUMN_NAME,
ROW_NUMBER() over(order by COLUMN_NAME) as COUNTER_COLUMN
from MY_TABLE t
;
```

Comment: This is ok but you might also be interested in... https://my.vertica.com/docs/9.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/Sequences/UsingAutoIncrementandIdentitySequences.htm%3FTocPath%3DAdministrator's%2520Guide%7CManaging%2520Tables%7CSequence%2520Types%7C_____2